# Linked List prints symbols instead of words during second iteration

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am very much a beginner in C so I know my code may look like crap. All I wanted to do was make a linked list with a struct that holds an array of chars and `int` for frequency. It reads lines from a test file and simply prints out the file. It reads the file correctly, iterates over the linked list the first time and prints it out correctly. However, on the second iteration of the linked list, it prints out the correct number of lines and the correct integer, but the words are replaced by symbols. I have looked everywhere and I just need some help. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Word_MAX_LENGTH 255

struct WordFreq
{
    char word[Word_MAX_LENGTH];
    int frequency;
    struct WordFreq *next;
} WordFreq;

struct WordFreq *head = NULL;

void insert(struct WordFreq *newNode)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return;
    }

    struct WordFreq *current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Please run as %s [filename]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("File (%s) does not exist\n", argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    struct WordFreq *line = malloc(sizeof(struct WordFreq));

    if (line == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot do dynamic memory managment\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("File content in %s:\n", argv[1]);

    while (fscanf(f, "%s %d", line->word, &(line->frequency)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", line->word, line->frequency);

        insert(line);

        line = malloc(sizeof(struct WordFreq));

        if (line == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot do dynamic memory management");
            return;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    // To keep head intact for sorting portion
    struct WordFreq *current = head;
    
    printf("\nContent of linked list:\n");

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", current->word, current->frequency);
        struct WordFreq *temp = current;
        current = current->next;

        free(temp);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n\n");
    current = head; 
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", current->word, current->frequency);
        current = current->next;
    }
    free(current);
    free(line);
}
```

Very appreciative of any help. Quite sad that I have been programming a while, but I want to learn C because I want to learn the ins and outs of why programs do what they do to help for future endeavors.

Comment: You have one loop where you `free` all nodes in your list. Then you iterate the list again, using the now non-existing nodes. That leads to *undefined behavior*. You will also call `free` on a null pointer after the last loop, but that's okay because it's specified to do nothing.

Comment: OT: "_// To keep head intact for sorting portion_" You'll avoid a world of pain by filling a BST (binary search tree) right now, instead of a simple Linked List. As you populate the nodes of the tree, you're already sorting them...

Comment: Avoid using global variables. Either pass a pointer to head or return its value from insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You free the linked list during the first iteration, so the second iteration has undefined behavior because `head` has become an invalid pointer and the contents of the memory of the list nodes have changed. Reading from them has undefined behavior, anything can happen including the program stopping with a invalid memory access or random output as you observe.

You should write functions: one to print the list contents and a separate one to free the list.  Combining these operations creates confusion and leads to logical errors such as this one.

Also note these remarks:

- the return type of `main` is `int`. Modify the `return` statements to return `1` on error and `0` on success, ie: normal operation.
- `printf("File (%s) does not exist\n", argv[1])` might not be the correct diagnostic: the file might exist but `fopen` will fail if the process does not have the proper access priviledges.  You could use `errno` and output the appropriate error message:

  ```
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <string.h>

   [...]

       if (f == NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
           return 1;
       }
  ```
- instead of `fscanf(f, "%s %d", line->word, &(line->frequency)) != EOF` you should test for `fscanf()` success at performing both conversion: it should return `2`.  Better even: read the input one line at a time with `fgets` and use `sscanf()` to convert the line contents and report conversion errors with an explicit message that includes the offending input line.
- `head` is freed twice: `free(current)` at the end must be removed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_MAX_LENGTH 255

struct WordFreq {
    char word[WORD_MAX_LENGTH];
    int frequency;
    struct WordFreq *next;
} WordFreq;

struct WordFreq *head = NULL;

void insert(struct WordFreq *newNode) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        struct WordFreq *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
    newNode->next = NULL;
}

void print_list(const struct WordFreq *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%s %d\n", node->word, node->frequency);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void free_list(struct WordFreq *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        struct WordFreq *temp = node;
        node = node->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[WORD_MAX_LENGTH + 20];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please run as %s [filename]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("File content in %s:\n", argv[1]);

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {
        struct WordFreq *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if (node == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate node for %s\n", line);
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf(line, "%254s %d", node->word, &node->frequency) == 2) {
            printf("%s %d\n", node->word, node->frequency);
            insert(node);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid line: %s\n", line);
            free(node);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    printf("\nContent of linked list:\n");

    print_list(head);
    // ...
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok well I deleted the free(temp) and now it works. I was thinking that by making a new pointer pointing to the link list I was preserving it, but actually when I was freeing temp I was freeing the actual node because temp is just a pointer that points to the data. So no matter if I make 100 pointers, freeing one if it points to the data will overwrite the data. Thank you everyone for help, will definitely make those changes.

Comment: @dirthogger: exactly. Mastering the concept of pointers vs arrays and structures is a fundamental C skill. Welcome to C programming.

Comment: Thank you, definitely have a long way to go before I can contribute to Linux kernel development or malware analysis.

Comment: One thing I dont understand is if I freed the memory space, why does the last while loop print out the correct number of line and the correct number?

Comment: @dirthogger: there is no guarantee of anything but a possible explanation is the memory pointed to by `head` and the `next` links have not changed so the loop works, but the char array `word` has been changed by `free` as part of the arena internal bookkeeping, so it appears as random characters in the output.  The behavior is undefined, anything can happen, you may observe different behavior on a different machine, with a different compiler, or even just at another time.